# Why do Abel players backdash after Falling Sky?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, ultra-street-fighter-iv

I've seen plenty of matches where strong Abel players (KSK, RicoSuave), after a hard knockdown (from falling sky), they will back dash, then roll forward.

Why do all the players back dash? Is this to set up an unblockable or something?

Comment: It is probably simply to reorganize their attacks and getting the upper hand again.

Comment: It's a setup/mixup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975212-super-street-fighter-iv/55529245):

> Posted by user **Kalm20**:
>
> High level Abel's actually favour the mixup that comes after a Falling
>   Sky, because it's much more ambiguous, and arguably puts them in
>   better position.
>
> After a Falling Sky, you'll see them backdash immediately and do a
>   roll, right? That's an **ambiguous roll setup**, where your opponent can't
>   tell which side you'll land on because the unique spacing/ untechable
>   knockdown ends up putting Abel right where his roll will end inside
>   the opposing character's body while they get get up, and as such they
>   have to guess which side to block. Not only that, but you get a tiny
>   bit of frame advantage where you can I think (THINK) meaty a cr. LP or
>   LK and combo from there. It's really effective once you're playing
>   someone who knows he can't reversal every time he gets knocked down.
>
> Crouching HP mixups are less tricky. There's basically 2 things to
>   take note of in this mixup. The hit animation of the opposing
>   character and the strength of the rolls you use. Usually you'd want to
>   use LK roll as the last one in the series. You know:
>
> Cr. HP xx Roll, normal xx LK Roll to whatever
>
> Because LK roll is the safest/leaves you with the most time to
>   buffer/do that whatever. Now that's one layer of the mixup gone. That
>   only leaves you with the normal you used to reset the opponent, and
>   the first roll (which actually has no effect on what side you will
>   eventually end up unless you used the HK roll to move you to the other
>   side the first time) you used to cancel the cr. HP. This is where the
>   hit animations come into play, because depending on which strength
>   normal you use, a different animation is triggered and that is what
>   determines which side you land on. A cr. LK or LP will net you an
>   animation with a tiny amount of knock back, enabling Abel to roll to
>   the other side.
>
> Any other roll cancellable normal will net you an animation with a
>   bigger knockback, resulting in Abel staying on the same side. It's not
>   like Sakura's resets where her timing can vary everything and have
>   them still be ambiguous, these positions/results are set in stone. As
>   such, once you've played enough Abels/seen the reset enough times, you
>   will actually KNOW which way to block. Then the Abel has to start
>   tossing in MK rolls at the end to offset what you know, but those are
>   much less safe and you need to have conditioned your opponent to
>   block. Otherwise, they'll just react. That's why they're not suited to
>   high level play, unless you know your opponent doesn't know the
>   tricks. They don't have to guess anymore. And without that...it's
>   nothing more than a fancy positioning maneuver.